# iPhone SDK - system for fetching xml based on date

Tags: iphone, xml, nsdatecomponents

Hi i am developing an application for my college. So far the user can check their schedule. I do that by parsing some xml via a url. Looks like this: http://test.com/test/action=schedule

The next feature i want to implement is so the user can jump 1 day forward by pressing a button. I can take the current date which is displayed in a label and add 1 day to it by using NSCalenderComponents. Nowna want to fetch the users schedule for tommorow and i can do that by using this url: http://test.com/test/action=schedule&Delta=1

Delta = 1 means the current date plus 1 day.

This works fine if the user click the button once, but how can i program it so the user is able to keep clicking the button. Am I doing i completely wrong or can anyone help me in the right direction.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Declare an int variable, and keep track of how many times the user had tapped the button.  Create your URL dynamically using that variable.

```
NSString *myUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"http://test.com/test/action=schedule&Delta=%d", 
                         myIntegerVariable];
```